# react JS, async await access promise value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have the following async function,

```
async function getScriptText(structure, dicto) {
        try {
            const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                const response = await {text:dicto[rand].text, title:dicto[rand].title}
                return response
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("errore:",error)
        }

    }
```

then I use it with

```
            const scriptModel =  [
{script: getScriptText(props.sessionItem["induction"], iDicto)} ]
```

but when logged scriptModel, I see the promise not the value, how to use the returned value please?

Comment: this is how javascript's `async` function works. once you declare them as `async` any value returned from the function will be wrapped in a promise.

Comment: Are you sure you want it to be an `async` function after all? Why are you `await`-ing a simple object?

Comment: thanks @RoboRobok it is looking in a long JSON dictionary, to compose the object

Comment: @manuelBetancurt are you using some sort of library that does it asynchronously? Because doing this with built-in JSON parser doesn't make sense - it's not async.

Comment: @RoboRobok, thanks, just doing the composition of the object from a JSON file, no library used, but need to wait untill is done in order to render the screen values, otherwise it crashes sometimes, as constructing the object from JSON file some times takes longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if using `async` makes sense in your case, but in order to read the value from the promise, you need to either use `.then()` or `await`:

With `.then()`:

```js
let scriptModel;

getScriptText(
    props.sessionItem["induction"],
    iDicto
).then(result => scriptModel = {script: result});
```

With `await`:

```js
let scriptModel;

(async () => {
    scriptModel = {
        script: await getScriptText(
            props.sessionItem["induction"],
            iDicto
        )
    };
})();
```

Comment: The snippets aren't  practical, an unchained promise will most likely result in race condition. This requires to adapt the place where scriptModel is used to asynchronous control flow